# Google Analytics 4 (GA4) - reading events include custom properties

Tags: java, google-analytics-4

we are using GA4 to monitor all installed application in our customers. And we need to know, which version is there. Our app is web app (WAR) in Tomcat.

Each page which is generated and sended to client browser contains this gtag script.

`gtag('config', 'OUR-COMON-GA4-ID', {'app_version': '1.0.1'});`

There we put additional config information (https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference#config) and this additional information is in GA4 joined to each logged event.

I need to help with reading this additional information, using official JAVA library for acces GA4 so that I can determine for each event the version of the application that generated it.

Does anybody know how to read events additional parameters via API

Thanks a lot

I try to add new dimension

```
addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("event_params.app_version"))
```

but it does not works.

I get error
INVALID_ARGUMENT: Field event_params.app_version is not a valid dimension.

without this dimension event_params.app_version I am able to read data successfully

```
static void sampleRunReport(String propertyId, String credentialsJsonPath) throws Exception {
    // [START analyticsdata_json_credentials_initialize]
    // Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying
    // the private key file.
    GoogleCredentials credentials =
        GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(credentialsJsonPath));

    BetaAnalyticsDataSettings betaAnalyticsDataSettings =
        BetaAnalyticsDataSettings.newBuilder()
            .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
            .build();

    try (BetaAnalyticsDataClient analyticsData =
        BetaAnalyticsDataClient.create(betaAnalyticsDataSettings)) {
      // [END analyticsdata_json_credentials_initialize]

      // [START analyticsdata_json_credentials_run_report]
      RunReportRequest request =
          RunReportRequest.newBuilder()
              .setProperty("properties/" + propertyId)
              .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("event_params.app_version"))
              .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("pagePath"))
              .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("date"))
              .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("sessions"))
              .addDateRanges(DateRange.newBuilder().setStartDate("2023-03-31").setEndDate("2023-04-02"))
              .addOrderBys(OrderBy.newBuilder().setDimension(DimensionOrderBy.newBuilder().setDimensionName("date"))).build();

      // Make the request.
      RunReportResponse response = analyticsData.runReport(request);
      // [END analyticsdata_json_credentials_run_report]

      //READ RESPONSE
```

Does anobody know how to read it ?

Thank a lot.